# VLC users. What happens when you exit while in the fullscreen mode (alt+f4)? Does it start in the same size as you have before going fullscreen?

Tags: release-loki, vlc

Can somebody that uses vlc tell me what happens in situation described in the title?

On mine, when i start vlc after exiting in fullscreen mode, it forgets the window size that i had before going to fullscreen mode.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, VLC behaves like that.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your reply.  Hopefully it gets fixed in a near future.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about elementary OS, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Hi. I understand, but i wanted to know if other elementary users are having the same issue as me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, https://superuser.com/a/368759/699547

1. Open any video and resize the VLC view screen to whatever size you want. Drag the corners and then go up to the Menu-bar at the top...
   Tools>Preferences>Interface>UNCHECK "Resize interface to video size" and click save.
2. Close your video and reopen to verify the correct setup.

Its a two-step process. Drag and size your viewing screen, then UNCHECK the "Resize Interface to video size" and SAVE.

Strictly speaking this question is off-topic for EOS stack overflow, however I've tried to answer it anyway.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately is not that. I always leave that option disabled.